Get SharePoint ListItemId by Document-ID in MS Graph API C# SDK
Im trying to get the listItemId based on the Document-ID of a item in the SharePoint Library.
By Document-ID I mean the ID that is automatically assigned to a document when it is uploaded to sharePoint.
I have already successfully retrieved the driveItemId using the Document-ID. This is what the method looks like:
public async Task<string> GetDriveItemIdByDocIdAsync(string driveId, string docId)
{
    try
    {
        var query = $"Dokument-ID:{docId}";

        var results = await _graphClient.Drives[driveId].SearchWithQ(query).GetAsSearchWithQGetResponseAsync();

        if (results.Value.Count == 1)
        {
            _logger.Info($"Found one document with documentId '{docId}' in drive '{driveId}'.");
            return results.Value.FirstOrDefault().Id;
        }
        else if (results.Value.Count == 0)
        {
            _logger.Info($"No document with documentId '{docId}' found in drive '{driveId}'.");
            throw new Exception($"No document with documentId '{docId}' found in drive '{driveId}'.");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Error($"More than one document with documentId '{docId}' found in drive '{driveId}'. Returning the first item with driveItemId == '{driveItemId}'");
            return results.Value.FirstOrDefault().Id;
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Error while trying to get last version of item with documentId '{docId}' in drive '{driveId}'. Exception: '{ex}'");
        throw;
    }

I need the listItemId to later read out the checkInComments of the different versions of the ListItem, as far as I know this is only possible via Lists, and not via Drives.
You do not need to answer directly with the C# SDK implementation, an https request is also sufficient. Thanks for your help

To get the SharePoint ListItemId, you can make use of below Microsoft Graph API query:
Posting details proof of work @user2250152
As you have DriveItemID you can pass it to get the list item ID
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DriveID/items/DriveItemID/listItem


You can make use of select to fetch only the ID:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DriveID/items/DriveItemID/listItem$select=id


And use the below code:
public class GraphService
{
    public GraphService(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantId)
    {
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential);
    }

    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public async Task<string?> GetListItemIdAsync(string driveId, string driveItemId)
    {
        try
        {
            var listItem = await _graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId].ListItem.GetAsync();

            return listItem?.Id;
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error while trying to get list item with driveItemId '{driveItemId}' in drive '{driveId}'. Exception: '{ex}'");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string clientSecret = "Secret";
        string tenantId = "TenanTID";

        var graphService = new GraphService(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId);

        
        string driveId = "DriveID";
        string driveItemId = "DriveItemID";

        try
        {
            var listItemID = await graphService.GetListItemIdAsync(driveId, driveItemId);
            Console.WriteLine($"List Item ID: {listItemID}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

The list item ID is fetched:


driveItem has a relationship to listItem, so you should be able to access listItem and it's id this way
GET /v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{driveItemId}/listItem

C#
var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].ListItem.GetAsync();

